# Socket IO Broadcast Emit sending to sender

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have an app where I need the users to be able to send a message. Right now, users can send a message and socket IO broadcasts the message, but the sender also receives. I need messages sent to go to everyone but sender

Current behavior: User A calls handleButton function, User A and User B receive broadcastMessage and console log guess

Wanted behavior: User A calls handleButton function. Only user B receives broadcastMessage and logs guess

Server code:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("upGuess", (guess, room) => {
        if (room) {
            socket.to(room).emit("broadcastMessage", guess);
        } else {
            socket.broadcast.emit("broadcastMessage", guess);
        }
    });
});
```

Client side Code:

```
socket.on("broadcastMessage", (guess) => {
    console.log(guess);
});

const handleButton = () => {
    socket.emit("upGuess", "TestGuess");
};
```